# Cast or convert varchar in SQL Server to INT

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting, type-conversion

I am trying to convert the following to an integer so that I can do calculations, from `123.456.789` to `123456789`.

However, when I try

```
CAST([Total number] AS INT)
```

OR

```
CONVERT(int, [Total number])
```

then I get an error

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '123.456.789' to data type int.

Comment: Do you require like this 123456789

Comment: That is exactly right

Comment: Add `WHERE replace([Total number], '.', '') NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'` to make sure only integers are converted.

Answer (score 5):

```
Declare @val varchar(100)='123.456.789'

SELECT CAST (REPLACE (@val,'.','') AS INT) As Intval
```

Comment: But now you declare only 1 value, the one in my example. How would you do this for multiple columns or multiple values? Better to use UPDATE and SET no?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the dot is not a fractional part divider and your number is integer (not float/decimal) - you can just remove dots from your string prior to conversion something like:

```
CAST(replace([Total number], '.', '') AS int)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use try_convert or try_cast even if it has any special characters it will return null in that case

```
Select try_convert(int, replace([Total number], '.', ''))
```

Comment: Nice one! Thank you Kannan :)

Answer (score 0):

Is this your requirement as below

```
 Declare @val TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY,Val varchar(100))

INSERT INTO @val
SELECT '356.345.789' UNION ALL
SELECT '123.456.333' UNION ALL
SELECT '444.124.444' UNION ALL
SELECT '347.456.555' UNION ALL
SELECT '123.666.789' UNION ALL
SELECT '678.432.789' UNION ALL
SELECT '789.456.111' UNION ALL
SELECT '123.457.123' UNION ALL
SELECT '333.111.789'


SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(Order by (SELECT 1)) AS Rno, 
       CAST(REPLACE (Val,'.','') AS INT) As Intval 
FROM @val
```